# Clickable jquery table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I generate a table on a page like so:

```
<table id="documents" class="table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>File Name::</th>
        <th>Date Uploaded</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    {{#each Documents}}
        <tr id="{{Name}}">
            <td id="name" name="name">{{Name}}</td>
            <td id="date" name="date">{{Date}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

using handlebars
And using jquery i make the table row clickable like so:

```
$(function(){
        $( "#documents tr" ).click(function() {
            var name = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html;
            alert(name);
        });
});
```

And im trying to display the value from the #name table data.
However it keeps giving me undefined, and i can't figure out how to get the data from the selected table row and the name table data object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**`.html()`**](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is a method not property hence you must invoke it by having parenthesis[`()`]

Change

```
var name = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html;
```

to

```
var name = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html();
```

**But** If you want to get `text` of the `element`, Use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `.html` but `.html()`

```
$(function(){
    $( "#documents tr" ).click(function() {
        var name = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html();
        alert(name);
    });
});
```